# Cannot find type 'INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode

I have recently begun designing an app extension. I mention that because all of a sudden my Siri Setup View Controller within my main app has been throwing me a "Cannot Find type 'INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate' in scope" error as well as "Cannot find type 'INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController' in scope."

I have been trying to figure this one out for a while. I am unsure what to do or even where to begin.

Any ideas?

(Yes I have tried cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data)

Answer (score 5):

Forgot IntentsUI import. Dumb mistake. Will leave it up just in case anyone else wondering...